How do I get an Afterglow Switch controller to work with my PC?
I noticed this hasn't been answered proper. But I've tried everything I could think of. It apparently "connects" but doesn't pair and the four green lights continue to cycle as if it's still trying to connect. I have grown to assume there's something as a whole wrong with my PC but I'm not entirely sure, I've had a regular Switch controller work with my PC, and this Afterglow is just a replacement as the last one's analog sticks completely died.

Try ReWASD, it claims to support PDP Afterglow Wave Wireless Controller

Wouldn't ReWASD require the controller to be able to send input in the first place? Which can't happen due to it not pairing.

What's the evidence that it's not pairing? Switch controller LEDs continuing to blink after connecting is normal, they are controlled by the application and don't reflect the connection state.
